# Valgrind with sfml

Tags: compiler-construction, valgrind, sfml

I am completely new to the use of Valgrind. Currently I have compiled an exe for the program to test on; however, the test brings up over 250k errors. This is the basic project made with a new sfml project. There is literally nothing to it but an image and a window along with the ability to close the program out. I compile it just fine, but as stated, Valgrind produces 250k+ errors. A couple of times it was like 10 million. Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

valgrind --leak-check=yes ./test

Comment: With nothing but an int main(), I am still getting over 2 million errors.. I don't understand!

Comment: What compilation switches are you using (valgrind can be sensitive to optimisations) ?

Comment: Can you show a minimal code that reproduces the problem?

Answer (score 0):

There is probably nothing wrong with it. On my system i got fglrx-driver(ati system) for opengl and it is pretty common that valgrind produces these. So these aren't actually memory leaks by sfml. These are not memory leaks you should bother about: most of them will come out of one library. Just put the errors in your default suppression file of valgrind, so that you are able to see your actual memory leaks.